# docker openerp can not start - stop

Tags: odoo, docker

I have created a docker openerp container. The first launch from the browser is good, I can either create newdatabases either restore previous ones.

Then I do a `docker stop openerp` followed by a `docker start openerp`.
Accesing again from the browser doesnt work anymore. I get the background interface but with openerpserver errors.

I have tried it using my own docker images built from sources that can be found on [github yvnicolas/docker-openerp repo](https://github.com/yvnicolas/docker-openerp) as well as using the tinyerp/ubuntu-openerp repo from Dockerhub with similar effects.

Here is the error trace I get :

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1427, in load
    action = req.session.model(action_type).read([action_id], False, ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3679, in read
    result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3800, in _read_flat
    res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, user, context=context, values=res)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1145, in get
    result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 211, in _search_view
    'search', context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/account/account_invoice.py", line 363, in fields_view_get
    res = super(account_invoice,self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2278, in fields_view_get
    xarch, xfields = self.__view_look_dom_arch(cr, user, result['arch'], view_id, context=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 1930, in __view_look_dom_arch
    fields = self.fields_get(cr, user, None, context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3597, in fields_get
    res_trans = translation_obj._get_source(cr, user, self._name + ',' + f, 'field', context['lang'])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in lookup
    r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_translation.py", line 336, in _get_source
    (lang or '', types, tools.ustr(name)))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting will happen when you run start and stop?  Stopping a running container will lose all in-memory data, and all processes.  You will need to restart any processes that happened to be running, by e.g. issuing the start CMD/ENTRYPOINT again.  But all the databases you created will be gone.  If you want to keep the processes and data, you can try the new pause/unpause commands, new in 0.12.0.  This is a snapshotting mechanism and may do what you are thinking start and stop should do.

Comment: I am expecting the same kind of behaviour that I get on a dedicated machine when I stop/start openerp by stopping its service or processes. Docker seems to do a pretty good part of the job as after my docker stop and docker start it seems that my launch script from my ENTRYPOINT is launched again and desired processes both for postgres and openerp are launched well. It just seems that openerp is messed up somewhere between the web interface and the database content. The database content is still there as I have created my postgres cluster inside a data container volume.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is some kind of state retention going on.  You do your docker run and it boots everything up, but a docker stop will keep the container state and a docker start restarts that same container rather than creating a new image.  If you did a docker rm then a docker run to create a new container does it work?

Comment: Actually, sice the whole purpose is not to reload the data everytime, I have tried your suggestion keeping the data container. If I start from a brand new empty data container, it works but I have to restore "manually" my base which is not what I want to. If I start a new execution container with the existing data, I have the same problem...